# Unable to see the user in peer docker container that got created in fabric-ca container

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I'm running a Hyperledger fabric network which is the sample basic-network. My configuration is one peer, one ca and one orderer. In `crypto-config.yml`, I've one peer and only one user.

I generated the certificates for the network by running the command `cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yml`.

When I looked for the user certificate in the fabric-ca docker container, I couldn't find it which to some extent makes sense because certificates got generated using the `cryptogen` tool. But now I've registered and enrolled a new user in fabric-ca container and I want him to invoke the chaincode. How can I do that? How can I pass the certificates from fabric-ca to peer container? And let's suppose even if I do that using `docker cp` command, will it be the correct way to pass the certificates?

What will I need to do if I want the new user to invoke the chaincode from cli container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the basic-network, when the cli container is created an environment variable is set: 
`CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`

You will need to reset this variable to direct to the folder for your new ID then you should be able to use the `peer chaincode invoke` command which will use the new credentials.

(I found a small problem when testing this - the invoke command is looking for an `admincerts` subfolder under `msp` so I just copied the signcerts folder to admincerts.)